# Pandas melt or pivot df multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My df has this structure, what I want to achieve is to transform the df into df where the column headers t1 - t6 will be values with the corresponding timestamps.

`import pandas as pd`

`df = {'id': [1, 2], 'type': ['sample_eu', 'sample_japan'],'t1': [20,90], 't2': [40, 80], 't3': [10, 12], 't4': [33, 46], 't5': [14, 26], 't6': [36, 46]}`
`df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)`

my desired output looks like the following:

| id | type | timepoints | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | sample_eu | t1 | 20 |
| 1 | sample_eu | t2 | 40 |
| 1 | sample_eu | t3 | 10 |
| 1 | sample_eu | t4 | 33 |
| 1 | sample_eu | t5 | 14 |
| 1 | sample_eu | t6 | 36 |
| 2 | sample_japan | t1 | 90 |
| 2 | sample_japan | t2 | 80 |
| 2 | sample_japan | t3 | 12 |
| 2 | sample_eu | t4 | 14 |
| 2 | sample_japan | t5 | 26 |
| 2 | sample_japan | t6 | 46 |

with
`df.stack()` the whole df get transposed. How can certain columns be fixed while I stack others ?

Comment: `df.melt(['id', 'type'], var_name='timepoints')`